# Android : Centering Items in a ListVIew

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have just started learning Android and thought of a simple project to help me learn.

I have created a simple menu using a ListView on a LinearLayout.

What I want to do is center the text in the ListView and also center the ListView in the layout.

I tried setting gravity to center-Hozitonal but that didn't work.

Comment: workaround for centering the text is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168424/center-text-items-in-listview). It's a little different kind of approach (through code). But I guess the answer below, is better as it defines the 'gravity' property at xml level itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `gravity` (not `layout_gravity`) attribute to center text. Make sure that you also set `layout_width` is set to `"fill_parent"`. For example, in `my_text_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

And then you can use `R.id.my_text_view` as your resource id.

Comment: But do I have a text view?  All I have done is stuck a listview on a linearlayout and then added some items to it via code

Comment: By adding the line above to your xml you'll have the TextView.

Comment: Wicked I understand except that <TextView bit does not compile,  Should it be Android.TextView or something

Comment: Did you figure it out? If you're using a `ListView` you'll probably have to supply a resource id when you create your adapter or inflate your own in your adapter's `getView` method.