# Issue with ListView alignment

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in xml with both `layout_width` and `layout_height` as `fill_parent`.

I am using default layout supplied by android as `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.But as it is default supplied by android i cannot make alignment in center.Default alignment is left-side. Anyway to do that.I know i can make my own textview and give as R.layout.my_textView.But anyway to make listview items in center with that defaule layout.

Comment: `android:gravity="center" ` might help you to align center

Comment: android:gravity="center_horizontal"  perhaps too? here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499555/android-layout-centering-in-relativelayout-for-custom-listview

Comment: guys just read my question 2 times at least please and then give answer.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing where each row loads in the middle of the listview.

Comment: @PradeepBhatu copy that default xml file and make your own with gravity center.

Answer (score 0):

can you put up your layout? the error may be that your missing "android:gravity="center""

Comment: no eroor is there.Red my question."android:gravity="center"" is not availablke in listview.Even if i am giving it it is not working.

Comment: @AndroidKiller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305632/android-centering-items-in-a-listview  I don't think you have to do it with your ListView item but with your layout which you inflate in the getView() of your adapter for the row.

Comment: guys just read my question 2 times at least please and then give answer.

Comment: @AndroidKiller this link might enlighten you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304608/what-is-android-r-id-text1 practically you cannot do without overriding it elsewhere and how it looks like http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout and set `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

UPDATE: 
This is the layout for a row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Answer (score 0):

You could override part of the layout of the system `TextView` in the getView method of your adapter by setting the gravity, margin or anything else there when the view is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

for textview alignment in center you can create a custom row xml 
for creating custom row xml follow that document
http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/custom-listview-with-image-using-simpleadapter/

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ListView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Read my question again please