# Center text items in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How can I horizontally center-align text items of the `ListView` in my `Layout`? 
Honestly, I googled for at least an hour before asking such a basic question.

Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Remind..." />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewTimeInterval"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

         <-- . . . --/>
         <-- more lists of the same kind--/>
         <-- . . .--/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `gravity` of the `TextViews` be set in the custom items XML?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create your own layout for your listview item, something like this

Example:

textcenter.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your code, your have to do this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textcenter, R.id.textItem, functions);
listView.setAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: Your answer if valid. But I believe the OP is already using a custom `ListView` of some sort. It has the ID of `listviewTimeInterval`

Comment: Doesn't ListView itself control how the text appears in it? Why should I use separate layout?

Comment: Well, I misunderstood the role of layouts thinking they only needed for activities. Then I realized ListView is, in fact, a list of many views each having a certain layout.

Comment: you should change in TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 5):

I found it impossible to center the items in a ListView if the LisView itself is defined with
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
This does not make sence, because this parameter should only affect the position of the ListView and not its elements.

Anyway, changing the width of the list to match_parent allows to center the items with their (layout_)gravity attributes.

Comment: Thanks! Been trying to center a listview for hours.

Answer (score -4):

In the layout of the TextView for your customized ListView xml file use `android:gravity="center"` . That'll do it.

Comment: This is a bit short for an answer and could be a comment instead. Have you read the [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to answer questions on StackOverflow?